# Python return result is not alike "N()"

Tags: python

I made the method name is slide. and it must return the reference of it. Then, What should I do?.

First, I made this function like:

```
class N:
  def slide(self, i):
    #do something
    return self
```

This slide method must return "N()" but "<~~ obejct at x0000>"

Comment: Please update your question with your calling code. What do you want to do with the return value from `slide()`?

Comment: Your code isn't very clear, but I think you're looking for `__repr__`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/354577

Comment: I see you have updated the question, but its still not clear. Did you mean to write: `return "N()"`, or are you after the `__repr__()` method?

Answer (score -2):

Definitely depends on your calling code. But this, for example, will work as expected to return a reference to an instantiated object `N`:

```
class N:
  i = 1

  def slide(self, i):
    self.i = i;

    return self

n = N()
print(n.i) # 1

r = n.slide(2)
print(r.i) # 2
```

Comment: How does this meaningfully differ from what OP has in their question? Both define a class `N` with a method `slide()` that returns `self`. Why do you think OP is asking how to access `i`?

Comment: But in my python interpreter, it doesn't accept a class without an init function at all

Comment: `i` is just to demonstrate `slide()` works as expected. It doesn't different significantly from OP; but demonstrates a working way to call `slide()` and receive a reference in return.

Comment: I don't believe OP's question is in any way addressed here, but it is very unclear. OP needs to clarify their problem. I still think they just want to define a `__repr__()` for their class.